# Unsupervised Classification in Machine Learning

Tags: machine-learning, classification, unsupervised-learning

Clustering (eg: K-means , EM algorithm etc) is used for unsupervised classification by forming clusters in the data sets using some distance measurement between data points

My question is :
Other than clustering what can I use to perform unsupervised classification and how? Or is there no other option other than clustering for unsupervised Classification?

Edit: Yes I meant k-means

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Clustering is a general term that stands for the case where data points will be split into classes without any information about the true choices. So no matter what kind of algorithm you are applying, it will be a clustering if it is unsupervised classification.

Of course there are many different approaches depending on the case, data, problem and etc. If you could provide more context about your exact task, I might name some approaches.

Comment: Hi thankyou for your reply. I'm theoretically trying to understand what else can be done other than clustering to perform unsupervised classification. It would be very helpful if you could name a few approaches. But if the different approaches are eventually clustering the answer to my question is No other option, right?

Comment: Yes, the answer to your question is basically No. Clustering is a general term, where you split similar samples into groups with respect to a similarity measure without using the groundtruth labels.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is NO, clustering is not the only field under unsupervised learning. Unsupervised Learning is way more broader than only clustering. Clustering is just a sub-field of (or type of) unsupervised learning.

Little correction: KNN is not a clustering method, it is a classification algorithm. You probably meant to say k-means.

The essence of unsupervised learning is basically learning data without ground truth labels. Thus, the goal of unsupervised learning is to find representations of data given. The applications of unupervised learning vary a lot, though academically it is true that the field is less attractive to researchers due to its complexity and effort to build new stuff and/or make improvements.

[Dimension reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensionality_reduction) can be considered under unsupervised learning as you want to find a good representation of data in lower dimensions. They are also useful for visualizing high-dimension data. PCA, SNE, tSNE, Isomap, etc. are type of these applications.

[Clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis) methods are type of unsupervised learning as well where you want to group and label values based on some distance/divergence measure. Some applications could be K-means, Hierarchical clustering, etc.

[Generative models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generative_model), generative models model the conditional probability P(X|Y=y). The research in this field boomed since the publication of [GAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generative_adversarial_network) (see [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1406.2661)). GANs can learn the data distribution without seeing the data explicitly. Methods are various where GANs, VAE, Gaussian Mixture, LDA, Hidden Markov model.

You can read further [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unsupervised_learning) on unsupervised learning.

Comment: Hi thankyou for your reply. But as I have mentioned I'm talking about unsupervised classification and not learning.

Comment: Can I use GAN to perform unsupervised Classification?

Comment: @ruhuse There is not such thing called "unsupervised classification", if you mean clustering, just see clustering methods I provided the wiki link. At least you can observe what methods there are, and then research for those methods.